# get request working on api but post is giving error

Tags: angular, laravel

I am trying to call Laravel API in angular:

```
search(data){

 console.log(data);

 this.http.get('http://localhost:8000/flight',JSON.stringify(data))
    .subscribe(res=>{
        console.log(res);
  });

}
```

the above is working with GET request.

```
 search(data){
   console.log(data);
   this.http.post('http://localhost:8000/flight',JSON.stringify(data))
        .subscribe(res=>{
           console.log(res);
  });
}
```

but not working with POST request

this is the error i get :

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

even though i have my cors middelware written correctly

```
 return $next($request)->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true )
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers',' Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token');
```

Comment: It is CORS issue on the server

Comment: can you please just explain me sir iam new to laravel and angular

Comment: No sir , i dnt know any sir you need to enable CORS in lavel api https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors

Comment: but i have enabled it by writing the cors middleware and i have also added it in my RouteServiceProvider

Comment: The only way to know if you really wrote it correctly is to look at the network tab in your developer tools and see if your local server actually returns the CORS header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to make a change in the code i.e (Remove JSON.stringify) because it was sending string instead of json object

```
 search(data){
 console.log(data);
  this.http.post('http://localhost:8000/flight',data)
    .subscribe(res=>{
       console.log(res);
  });
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this in your post method:

in laravel server side :

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://localhost:3000"

(or)

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, If-Modified-Since, Cache-Control, Pragma");
```

Restarting apache is neccessary.

**post Method in angular**

```
search(data: any) {
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:8000/flight', data).map(res => {
        const jsonResponse = res.json();
        return jsonResponse;
    });
}
```